# How to save project in Android with about 10 variables?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, sharedpreferences

i am new to Android development. I have two activities **A** and **B**. In activity **A** I use a xml parser to gain objects with each about 10 strings included. I want to pass these objects to activity **B** and there should be a listview showing all the objects. Clicking on a object in the listview should show the 10 strings.

I am not sure if I have to use a SQLite database or if I only can use SharedPreferences? 
Or can I even store it on the internal memory?

The objects should be saved even if i kill the app.

Hope someone can give me some hints, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a database, if you want to search and index on the individual fields. Otherwise convert it to Json or some other format and save it in SharedPrefs

Comment: Just see tutorials about Bean and List and other Collection Classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may helps you

you can pass your string data both way as you like [1] Using Intent [2] Using Share Prefrence

like [1] Intent
in your First ActivityA

```
            Intent myintent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            myintent.putExtra("Name1", "your String");
            myintent.putExtra("Name2", "your String");
            myintent.putExtra("Name3", "your String");
            myintent.putExtra("Name4", "your String");
            startActivity(myintent);
```

in Second ActivityB

```
    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    if(null!=myintent.getExtras()){
    String Name1 = myintent.getExtras().getString("Name1");        
    String Name2 = myintent.getExtras().getString("Name2");        
    String Name3 = myintent.getExtras().getString("Name3");        
    String Name4 = myintent.getExtras().getString("Name4");        
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+Name,12).show();                              

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Recor Here..",12).show();

    }
```

like SharedPreferences[2]
in your First ActivityA

```
           Intent myintent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            SharedPreferences spref = this.getSharedPreferences("mynotifyid", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor spreedit = spref.edit();
            spreedit.putString("Name1", str1.toString());   
            spreedit.putString("Name2", str2.toString());   
            spreedit.putString("Name3", str3.toString());   
            spreedit.putString("Name4", str4.toString());   
            spreedit.commit();
            startActivity(myintent);
```

in your Second ActivityB

```
        SharedPreferences spref = context.getSharedPreferences("mynotifyid", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        String str1 = spref.getString("Name1","");
        String str2 = spref.getString("Name2","");
        String str3 = spref.getString("Name3","");
        String str4 = spref.getString("Name4","");
```

for your object saving purpose use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

Let these objects implement the interface `Serializable` so you can pass the objects to another Activity using an `Intent`
Maybe this small(!) example can help you:

```
public class MyModel implements Serializable {

    ...

}

public A extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
      ...
      //fetchData
      ...
      MyModel data = new MyModel(fetchedData);
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
      intent.putExtra("KEY", data);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public B extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtas();
      MyModel data = (MyModel) extras.getSerializable("KEY");

      ...
      //handle data
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those 10 strings I wouldn't use database.
SharedPreferences easy to use, lot of examples and will deal with your needs.
If a none string need later, than you can use  internal memory ( binary mode ), but now no reason, imho.

Comment: so even if I later have 5+ objects in my listview with each 10 strings the sharedpreferences are no problem?